# Full page alvarotrigo : Scroll

Tags: fullpage.js

I am using alvarotrigo full page js for wordpress. It works very fine, but there is only an issue for scroll.
As you may know, the basic structure is like this.

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">One</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Three</div>       
<div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

However there are sometimes a temporary (dynamic) div or script or style elementary by user's dynamic setting.

http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1477/

**As you see there are 2 example elementary by user's dynamic settings and scroll is not working to move "four". because of temp style tags, clear div.**

**Isn't it possible to work scrolling only for "[div class="section"]..[/div]"?**
then scroll doesn't need to care other elementary or html tags.
I have tried "sectionSelector". but it's not working for scrolling.

1 more question. The temp style is created by user's dynamic setting. Isn't it possible to move into `<head>`..`</head>` automatically? Maybe by script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have anything between sections. fullPage.js [requires a specific structure](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#required-html-structure) and you are not following it.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

You should be asking yourself, why do you have those `style` tags in between sections and not directly in the `<head>` where they belong.

Comment: I am glad to get the answer from the author. thank you so much for  great js. Yes, you are right. "style" has to be removed and we fixed. however we still have a problem with other div (no "section" div). please see this, I added some description to make u understand better. http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1483/ .. your fullPage is very great and even with wordpress which has some user settings. we are working with visual composer and there is only this problem makes it work. If scroll jumps ONLY DIV which has section class ( "<div class='section'>" ) then it should be much flexible to use. thanks

Comment: Additionally, we made structure like that. but users can make width settings with VC. when you make "stretch width", it creates 1 div (<div class="clear"></div>) next <div class="section">...</div>.. I really hope there is any way to scroll on ONLY "<div class="section">..</div>". thank you again!

Comment: Take a look at [this pull request](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/pull/85). It is related with your issue. But you'll have to modify fullpage.js for that: 

Feel free to create an issue in [the issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues).

Comment: Once again, very thank you for your answer and full page. I will have a look and create an issue there.